# Generic Go function to save bytes into a fixed-size byte array buffer

Tags: arrays, go, slice

How do I to write a generic Go function to push bytes into a byte array?

I suppose appending to a slice is not a perfect fit, because the array should not grow.
However the function should handle any array size.
I am considering to slice the array just to make the function accept any array size.
See my sketch below.

Is there a cleaner way?

Play: http://play.golang.org/p/Gii9-JM33E

```
func push(buf []byte, size int, b byte) (int, error) {
    max := len(buf)

    if max < 1 {
        return size, fmt.Errorf("buffer underflow: max=%d char=%d", max, b)
    }

    if size >= max {
        return size, fmt.Errorf("buffer overflow: size=%d max=%d char=%d", size, max, b)
    }

    buf[size] = b

    return size + 1, nil
}
```

Usage:

```
buf := [3]byte{}
size := 0
var err error
size, err = push(buf[:], size, 'a')
```

Comment: what's wrong with your current function?

Comment: @OneOfOne it requires the slicing of the array just to accept any array size. i feel it is clumsy to pass a slice plus its underlying array size... i hope there is a cleaner idiomatic way.

Comment: @JimB the array plus its size appear in the usage pattern i added below the function.

Comment: Ok, I see it. but why are you using an array in the first place?

Comment: For the record, using array[:] returns a slice with a pointer to the underlying array, so it's not really creating a new object.

Comment: I have the feeling you are focusing on the wrong thing here. What are you trying to solve ?

Comment: @fabrizioM the scenario is to use fixed-length buffers to store keyboard input. few buffer sizes are needed for special handling of specific input sub-states. i intended to use the same push() function for handling buffers (arrays) of any size. but now i am leaning towards Anonymous' suggestion of using fixed-length slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of an array is part if its type.

If there's a set of sizes you know you are going to accept, you could take a `buf interface{}` with a type switch on the sizes you want. I would assume you know the array sizes, since they must be constant at compile time.

Other than that you would need to use reflection to actually find the array size, and store elements within the array.

It's very infrequent you need to use an array instead of a slice. You may want to reconsider *why* you have to pass arrays of varying sizes around.

Comment: I have few arrays sizes, and was worried about having some fixed-size types (say [200]byte, [1000]byte, [64000]byte) appearing multiple times in the code. From you answer I see it may be wiser to define some custom array types (as in type Buf1 [100]byte, type Buf2 [1000]byte, type Buf3 [64000]byte) or to only use slices and prevent them from growing (as suggested by @Anonymous).

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly want to use a slice instead of an array. A slice has three things: an underlying backing array, a capacity, and a length. The capacity "`cap`" tells you the size of the underlying backing array.

So, you can use `append` after checking that `len(s) < cap(s)` to avoid any reallocation. Or if you want to make a function, perhaps something like this:

```
func pushByte(s []byte, b byte) ([]byte, error) {
    if len(s) == cap(s) {
        return s, errors.New("capacity reached")
    }
    return append(s, b), nil
}
```

You'd use it something like this:

```
s := make([]byte, 0, 10)
var err error
if s, err = pushByte(s, 10); err != nil {
    ... handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think your suggestion is indeed better.